# Can .htaccess be used to set file permissions?

Tags: htaccess, permissions, chmod

Is it possible to define file type permissions through .htaccess?  I have a site that uses .pl and .cgi scripts which require 0755 CHMOD.  The shared server setting is apparently geared for WordPress which require 0644 CHMOD as it is php-driven, so I'm guessing that my file permissions on .pl and .cgi occasionally get set to a default of 0644, causing "[an error occurred while processing this directive]."

I've tried adding this in the .htaccess, but get a 500 server error.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.  I do not have access to the httpd.conf file.

```
    chmod .htpasswd files 640
    chmod .htaccess files 644
    chmod php files 600
    chmod pl files 755
    chmod cgi files 755
    chmod cgi files 755
```

Answer (score 2):

Apache's .htaccess files cannot be used to set unix file permissions.

`chmod` is a command line tool for unix-like systems that is used to change the unix permissions of files on the filesystem. `chmod` is not an Apache or .htaccess construct, therefore `chmod` cannot be invoked through a .htaccess file - it can only be invoked by being executed on the server, through the command line or otherwise.

If you have ssh access to your server, you can use `chmod` there to set the proper file permissions. If you do not, there is a chance that your remote file browser GUI will let you set file permissions.

Answer (score 1):

As Maximillian says, you can't do it in .htaccess, but you can do it as a cron job.

Something like `0 * * * * /bin/chmod 755 /home/someuser/*.pl && /bin/chmod 600 /home/someuser/*.php`

Comment: Clever. If I'm reading it right, this cron job will reset the permissions to the correct ones every hour on the hour, forever.

Comment: Yes, it will reset permissions every hour (in this case) and only you can decide if they are "correct", you may need to tweak it to suit.

Comment: Sounds like this might be the best way to go.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Cruz Don't forget to "accept" the answer that ended up being most useful to you. Thanks!